# Which co-transmitters are released first?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neurotransmitter, neuron

I understand that a single neuron can release different neurotransmitters depending on the frequency of its stimulation (see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10818/). As the frequency of stimulation is increased, what is the order in which the neurotransmitters are released (i.e., which neurotransmitter is released at lower levels of stimulation and which are released at higher levels of stimulation)?

Comment: For a specific answer, you'd have to specify a specific neuron type. However, the source you link already discusses the general pattern, did you see that?

Comment: The source does say that smaller neurotransmitters are released first followed by neuropeptides; however I am looking for more specific information. Given the following list of neurotransmitters--glutamate, GABA, glycine, serotonin, histamine, dopamine, epinephrine, norepinephrine, endorphins, and acetylcholine--is there a _specific_ order to which is released first based on stimulation frequency?

Comment: Those are all small molecules. No, it's not a list like that and it would be inappropriate to make one.

Comment: Why are we unable to make such a list?

Comment: Because that's not how it works. Read again the source you linked: it's not indicating that neurons release a dozen neurotransmitters in some order, it's saying that some neurons might release a couple different things, and that peptides tend to be released at higher intensities.

Comment: Maybe think of it this way: if someone says "people eat more than one thing for dinner, they often have their dessert after their entree", you wouldn't give a list of entrees and ask which entree is eaten before the other entrees.